# Iframe permission denied error when developing locally: what are my options?

Tags: javascript, security, iframe, cross-domain, localhost

Here's what's going on:

I have an application `A` hosted on `a.mycompany.com` and an application `B` hosted on `b.mycompany.com`

Application `A` contains an iframe containing a page contained in the application `B`.

```
<!-- In A's index.html: -->
<iframe src="http://b.mycompany.com/something.html" >
```

I need to have either the parent talk to the iframe or the iframe talk to the parent.

It works fine when it's on the server, but when I'm developping locally I have two different servers running on different ports so I have to access them via:

```
http://a.mycompanydev.com:1234
http://b.mycompanydev.com:5678
```

And this leads to a security error since you can't communicate using JS with an iframe from a different domain/subdomain or using a different port.

What can I do??

---

*Related serverfault question: https://serverfault.com/questions/148171/how-to-map-localhost8080-to-simply-localhost*

Answer (score 2):

You can use fragment id messaging, which is a hack that uses window.location.hash (the part of the URL following #) to communicate.  This [test page](http://www.tagneto.org/blogcode/xframe/ui.html) has an example.  There are also libraries such as [Dojo](http://o.dojotoolkit.org/book/export/html/87) that facilitate this.

If you only need to support recent browsers, you can use [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.postMessage).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Could you elaborate a bit on what this is or how to accomplish that?

Comment: Here is the idea - Code in one window/iframe can write (but not read) the location of every other iframe on the page, even it belongs to another domain. So, iframe A will modify the url of iframe B by adding some content after the # (fragment identifier). Iframe B on the other hand will continuously monitor its url to identify the message. I believe there are libraries that insulate you from the gory details, you would just have to google it up.

Comment: If this is to be applied then you should go for a ready cooked solution like easyXDM. Its far beyond what Dojo (and any other library) has. But I would personally go with the proxy in this case, its not difficult and could be provided via a simple script.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the postMessage and location hash that Matthew mentions above, you may want to consider using a proxy server running locally. The proxy server will listen on port 80 and forward to the appropriate target port based on the domain name specified in the http request. Then you just access your website normally on port 80 and things should work properly.

Comment: The proxy idea is good but it would require everyone on the team to set up this proxy and this wouldn't be acceptable...